# Mongodb update array inside of an object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I can't write a query that would update a value of an array that is inside of an object:

Let's say I have a collection that has document entries with the structure like below (There are 2 entries in the example but actually there are a few thousand that I need to update in my db)

```
/* 1 */
{
    "name" : "Bob",
    "info" : {
        "species" : "human",
        "addresses" : [ 
            "one",
            "two"
        ]
    }
},
/* 2 */
{
    "name" : "John",
    "info" : {
        "species" : "human",
        "addresses" : [ 
            "two",
            "three"
        ]
    },
}
```

How can I update all documents in this collection so that all addresses in `info.addresses` array with value `one` would be changed to have value `four`?

[Examples](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update-array/) in mongo db documentation solve such cases when arrays are not inside objects, but I can't make them work with arrays inside objects

Example - this query should update all info.addresses arrays for all documents and change the entry values from `one` to `four`

```
db.getCollection('test').update({"info.addresses": "one"},{ $set: { "info.addresses.$" : "four" } })
```

Comment: That looks like 2 input objects, what output are you trying to achieve?  Have you tried anything?  Encountered any specific errors?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying, the 2 objects are an example of 2 documents in my collection, I will update the description and add the queries I tried

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
db.getCollection('test').update({"info.addresses": "one"},{ $set: { "info.addresses.$[]" : "four" } })
```

Notice how I added square brackets "[]" in the array specified in $set. It ($[]) is a positional operator in mongodb. You can read more about it in the Mongodb docs.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/

Comment: Thanks! And if it did the trick, I'd be grateful if you could mark a green tick.

Answer (score 0):

replace `update` to `updateMany`
for update all info.addresses arrays.

`db.getCollection('text').updateMany(
    {'info.addresses':'one'},
    {$set:{'info.addresses.$':'two'}}
  )`